# How do logic chips (74LS, HC, ...) provide output=Vcc/0V when all standalone diodes and transistors suffer voltage drops?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

If you use a transistor to pull signal to high from a Vcc of 5V, signal only goes to 4.5V or so because of voltage drop over the transistor.

Likewise if you use a transistor to pull signal to ground, signal is still stuck at 0.5V because of the voltage drop...

But logic chips, though they consist of transistors, act differently. How?

Comment: [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS). MOSFETs don't have inherent junction drops like BJTs do.

Comment: Depends on the transistor type and the current load.  A CMOS output, with say 40 ohm Rds, can be nearly 5V and nearly 0V with no load (like another CMOS input with 1uA load current - 0.000001 * 40 ohm = 0.00004 voltage developed across the transistor.  BJTs on the other hand almost always have 0.5V to 0.7V Vce, so the High is that much less and the Low is that much higher.

Comment: I tried using a 2N7000 as a diode, still got a voltage drop

Comment: @Alonda You do obtain a voltage drop across the diode when you use it as a diode. When it's turned on with appropriate gate drive, you will not see an inherent voltage drop aside from a current-dependent ohmic one. When in a CMOS circuit, gate drive is provided and hence you shouldn't expect it to operate as a diode when the output is driven low.

Comment: How much current, Ids,was flowing?  If you want a really small drop, use a MOSFET with a much smaller Rds, like AOD514 with just 0.04 to 0.05ohm Rds vs 1.8 to 5.3ohm at 75mA for the 2N7000

Comment: I thought I was being clever, connecting signal to source and gate, with a cap on drain to store power for a small circuit that would drive signal low to transmit data back to powersource. estimated 20mA max needed. voltage on cap still dropped by 0.7V or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I can completely answer your question here. To do that would require a more-or-less complete review of the design of LS and HC logic gates. But I think there are a few critical points you should think about as you come to an answer yourself.

1. The HC logic family is a CMOS family. There aren't any inherent diode drops in MOS transistors like there are in BJTs.
2. The LS logic family is a TTL family. In fact, these gates don't drive their outputs particularly close to the high-voltage rail when outputting logic "high". So in this case your intuition is at least somewhat correct.
3. However, when driving low, the output is only limited by the \$V_{ce(sat)}\$ characteristic of about 0.2 V (or lower if the sinking current is low) rather than by a pn junction drop.

To get a brief look at why, here's a schematic of a 74LS02:

[image]

You can see that when driving high, the output is actually limited to about **2** diode drops below VCC.

But when pulling low, the BJT (the one with its collector connected to the output) can be pushed into the saturation operating regime, allowing output voltages down to a couple 100 mv.

Comment: 2N7000 is N-channel MOSFET, your diagram is for the wrong logic family.

Comment: @CrossRoads, the question asks about HC and LS logic. If they want to ask about a 2N7000, they need to edit the question.

Comment: Sorry, got mixed up with the OP's testing comment.

Answer (score 3):

You are taking knowledge about one kind of circuit and applying it to all kinds of logic chips.

Logic devices that use bipolar transistors, such as TTL, are limited by the \$V_{cesat}\$ of the transistors, so they can't pull the output very close to ground or to Vcc (unless the current is near zero).

MOS transistors work much differently, and they can in fact drive the output voltage very close to Vdd or ground for low values of output current.

You should compare the \$V_{OL}\$ and \$V_{OH}\$ specifications of different kinds of logic chips to get an idea of how they really behave.